# In mithril.js, onremove and onbeforeremove events not firing, while oninit and oncreate are

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

File `TodoApp.js`:

```
...
const Todo = {
  oninit(vnode) {
    ...
    // ok
  },
  oncreate() {
    ...
    // ok
  },
  onbeforeremove() {
    ...
    // not firing
  },
  onremove() {
    ...
    // not firing
  }
};
...
```

I was trying to do some cleanup in `onremove` or `onbeforeremove`, but both are not working.
Is there something like `componentWillUnmount` of React in mithril.js?

Comment: onremove and onbeforeremove only fires when your component is going out of the dom. It seems like component is not detaching, instead its updating the same component.

You can check it via firing onupdate and onbeforeupdate events. If they are firing onupdate event instead of oncreate event, then your component is updated instead of recreation.

Answer (score 2):

They should be similar, except `onbeforeremove` only applies to the topmost element being detached, as I understand it.  I think maybe something else is causing those to not fire.  Are you sure the TODO is not being hidden with css or another error is being silenced before the hooks can be executed?

Maybe you need to post more of your code to debug.

I made a simple example, using **MithrilJS 2.0.4**, that demonstrates the difference between `onbeforeremove` and `onremove`.

after toggle on:

```
TODO.oncreate <div>​…​</div>​
TODOContent.oncreate <div>​Get something done​</div>​
```

after toggle off:

```
TODO.onbeforeremove <div>​…​</div>​
TODO.onremove <div>​…​</div>​
TODOContent.onremove <div>​Get something done​</div>​
```

The first click of the button shows the `TODO` and `TODOContent` and the second click of the button destroys the `TODO` and `TODOContent`.  `onbeforeremove` is only called for `TODO` but `onremove` is called for both `TODO` and `TODOContent`.

```
const TODOContent = {
  oncreate: function (vnode) {
    console.log('TODOContent.oncreate', vnode.dom);
  },
  onbeforeremove: function (vnode) {
    console.log('TODOContent.onbeforeremove', vnode.dom);
  },
  onremove: function (vnode) {
    console.log('TODOContent.onremove', vnode.dom);
  },
  view: function () {
    return m('div', 'Get something done');
  }  
}

const TODO = {
  oncreate: function (vnode) {
    console.log('TODO.oncreate', vnode.dom);
  },
  onbeforeremove: function (vnode) {
    console.log('TODO.onbeforeremove', vnode.dom);
  },
  onremove: function (vnode) {
    console.log('TODO.onremove', vnode.dom);
  },
  view: function () {
    return m('div', m(TODOContent));
  }
};

function TODOWrapper(vnode) {
  let show = false;
  function toggle(e) {
    show = !show;
  }
  return {
    view: function (vnode) {
      return m('div', [
        m('button[type=button]', {onclick: toggle}, 'toggler'),
        show ? m(TODO) : null,
        ]);
    }
  }
}
  

m.mount(document.body, {view: function () { return m(TODOWrapper);}});
```